# MongoDB-mongoose does not respond to REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I have a strange issue with MongoDB-mongoose, which does not respond to REST API
mongoose version - 4.11.3
Mongo DB shell version 3.4.6
Everything is local on my computer

Connection to Mongo DB is the following:

server.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connected correctly to db");
});
...
var app = express();
var tasks = require('./server/routes/taskRouter');
app.use('/api/tasks',tasks);
```

The log "Connected correctly to db"  is printed.

Schema (tasks.js)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var taskSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
var Task = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
module.exports = Task;
```

And finally taskRouter.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Task = require('../models/tasks');
var taskRouter = express.Router();
taskRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

taskRouter.route('/')
.get(function (req, res, next) {
Task.find({}, function (err, task) {
        console.log("result"+task)
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(task);
    });
})

.post(function (req, res, next) {
    var task = new Tasks();
    console.log ('the name is '+req.body.name);
    task.name = req.body.name;
    task.save(function(err){
      console.log ("arrived there");
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json({message: "Task created"});
    });
})
```

As you see, everything is by the book .
But I never get any logs from task.save and Task.find

My 'morgan' logger shows just the following logs:

```
GET /api/tasks - - ms - -
POST /api/tasks - - ms - -
```

Postman is stuck on "Loading", until receives a timeout: Could not get any response.
All simple operation on the tasks collection in Mongo DB shell are performed without any problem.
What happens with mongoose?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a separate file config.js with the following code :

```
module.exports = {
    'database': 'mongodb://localhost:27017/yourdatabasename'
}
```

**server.js:**

```
...
var config = require('./config'); // get our config file
...
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        ...
         mongoose.connect(config.database, { useMongoClient: true }); 
    mongoose.connection.on('open', function(err, doc){
        console.log("connection established");
        var app = express();
        var tasks = require('./server/routes/taskRouter');
        app.use('/api/tasks',tasks);

        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
        db.once('open', function() {
          console.log("Connected correctly to db");
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, but adding the config didn't help. I found a walk-around , when moved connection to the database (mongoose.connect ...) from server.js file to taskRouter.js. It's fine if I'm going to work on one route, but can anyone figure out what is the problem of connection to a database and performing actions on it in different files?